# select a string between two string

Tags: c#

I have an XML loaded to string  `param` like this

```
    <param>
  <ClientID></ClientID>
  <CarrierSCAC></CarrierSCAC>
  <StatusCode></StatusCode>
  <BatchNumber>20</BatchNumber>
  <SQL>
    ClientID<21
  </SQL>
</param>
```

From this string I want to slice out  `ClientID<21` , I have tried some thing like this

```
       int start = param.IndexOf("<SQL>") + 1;
        int end = param.IndexOf("</SQL>", start);
        string result = param.Substring(start, end - start);
```

but it gives me another result like this

```
SQL>ClientID<21
```

Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When retrieving the index of a string, it gets where that string starts. So what you need to do is to not do `indexOf("")+1` but rather add the length of the string you are looking for; `indexOf("")+5`

Comment: Why not use an xml parser? would be much simpler and less error prone

Comment: By the way, wouldn't be better if you use some XML parsing instead?

Comment: you should use some xml parser for this or atleast regex

Comment: The string is not valid XML so a parser would not work

Comment: Your param string is not valid XML… you have to escape the “<” between the <SQL>-Tags as “&lt;”… on the other hand, you don’t use a XmlReader or something… but you should be aware of this

Comment: @MarcelB i want to correct that one before parcing it to XMl, thats why I am trying to slice out that string and replace it with “&lt;”

Comment: @adrianm - Whether or not it is valid, doesn't make it any less of a correct approach. The op states they have an xml file and it should be treated as such - even if time must be spent making it valid. (For the record the bigger problem for me is this looks like a way to store a sql query which opens this up to easy injection)

Comment: @Athul shouldn’t that be done when then XML is generated and not afterwards?

Comment: @MarcelB  For Now, I don't have control over XML generation :(. So I have to live with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your problem, your code should be:

```
int start = param.IndexOf("<SQL>") + 5;
int end = param.IndexOf("</SQL>", start);
string result = param.Substring(start, end - start);
```

`IndexOf` returns the index of the first occurence (which in your case would be the `<` character

---

But you also should consider reading the xml with a appropiate model. So you could create a class something like this (not sure about the datatypes though):

```
public class Wrapper
{
  public Model Param;
}

public class Model
{
  public string ClientID;
  public string CarrierSCAC;
  public string StatusCode;
  public int BatchNumber;
  public string SQL;
}
```

Then reading the input:

```
var input = "<param>....</param>";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Wrapper));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(input))
{
  result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  var sql = result.Param.Sql; // this would be your string you are looking for
}
```

As others in comments already stated: You would have to make sure the XML is valid! The SQL string `ClientID<21` is not a valid string, because it contains the `<`.